# Unable to read certain registry keys in C

Tags: c, windows, registry

I'm using RegOpenKeyEx() and RegQueryValueEx() to try and get the value for six keys in the Windows registry. I'm able to do it for four of the six but am failing on certain others.

```
wchar_t * getRegKeyValue(HKEY rootKeyToGet, LPCWSTR subKeyToGet, LPCWSTR valueToGet)
{
    HKEY resultHKey = 0;
    wchar_t resultString[255] = L"";
    DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
    DWORD resultSize = 255;

    // See if the subkey exists. If it does, get its value.
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(rootKeyToGet, subKeyToGet, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &resultHKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegQueryValueEx(resultHKey, valueToGet, NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE) &resultString, &resultSize);
    }

    RegCloseKey(resultHKey);
    resultHKey = NULL;

    RegCloseKey(rootKeyToGet);
    rootKeyToGet = NULL;

    return resultString;
}
```

The following are some successful calls:

```
swprintf(buffer, L"&ie=%s", getRegKeyValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer", L"Version"));

swprintf(buffer, L"&os=%s.", getRegKeyValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"CurrentVersion"));

wcscat(url, getRegKeyValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"CurrentBuild"));
```

Example of an unsuccessful call:

```
wcscpy(buffer, getRegKeyValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"CSDVersion"));
```

I'm able to open the key in the unsuccessful call but the query for that value returns an empty string. I'm running Visual Studio as an administrator. Have been scratching my head for the last day on where I am going wrong.

**Update: The code returned is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. The codes are most definitely shown to exist in regedit.**

Comment: There are multiple problems here. You are requesting write access even though you only intend to read. You are returning a pointer to a local variable. Your `resultSize` is initialized incorrectly. You are closing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. You never check the error code from `RegQueryValueEx`. That last bit explains why you're getting nothing back.

Comment: What are the dangers of requesting more access than I need? I recently added the RegCloseKey(rootKeyToGet) in at an attempt to solve the problem. What negative effects does this have? I will check that error code.

Comment: If you request more access than you need, then the request may fail because you don't have one of those extra accesses that you never cared about. And closing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is probably a bad idea since you're closing a key you never opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you have a 32 bit process and a 64 bit machine. When this happens, registry redirection confounds matters.  Attempts to read `HKLM\Software\...` get redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow64Node\...`. So you need to open the 64 bit view of the registry with the `RegistryView` enumeration.

Comment: It appears that you're right about the key not being present in my wow6432node stuff. Why do I even have a 32 bit registry with seemingly  congruent entries? Seems redundant. Is it in place to that 32 bit applications can access it?

Comment: Yes, 32 bit processes have a separate view of some parts of the registry. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Note that `GetVersionEx` is the supported way of getting the operating system version and CSD version. Make it do the work of finding the right registry keys.

Comment: @Raymond Chen It never occurred to me to look at which keys were being looked at. But you are quite right that registry hacking for version info is bad.

Comment: Thanks fellas. There are some other third party keys that I have found live within Wow6432 so I'll need to manually extract those using some logic, however.

Comment: If you are on .net 4 then you should use [RegistryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx). Otherwise you need to P/invoke - yeuch!