# Can order matter when reading the Windows Registry?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

It seems that order matters on reading some keys from the registry, which surprises me.
I created `fake_entry` shown below via `Regedit`.

[image]

When I read `fake_entry` immediately after a call to `RegOpenKeyEx()`, it works. If I read anything else before my `fake_entry`, the read to `fake_entry` fails.

Example that fails:

```
openResult=RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full"), 0, KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &root);
readResult1=RegQueryValueEx(root, _TEXT("InstallPath"), NULL, NULL, data1, &size);
readResult2=RegQueryValueEx(root, _TEXT("fake_entry"), NULL, NULL, data2, &size);
```

In the above, the `InstallPath` read works and the `fake_entry` read fails with "Error 2, `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`."

Example that works:

```
openResult=RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full"), 0, KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &root);
readResult2=RegQueryValueEx(root, _TEXT("fake_entry"), NULL, NULL, data2, &size);
readResult1=RegQueryValueEx(root, _TEXT("InstallPath"), NULL, NULL, data1, &size);
```

In the above, both reads work.

Why does one work and the other fail? Can it really be order? Do I have to call `RegOpenKeyEx()` for each time I call `ReqQueryValueEx()`? My poking around on the internet appears to show otherwise.

Yes, I understand this isn't a registry location I should be changing. I stumbled upon this as I [was learning about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593852/cannot-read-registry-entry-in-c) `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` and am curious why order appears to matter.

Running Windows 7, 64 bit, C++ in Visual Studio 2010, using ASCII character encoding.

Comment: There's something weird in how you reuse one variable `size` for two consecutive calls as the in-out parameter. This may cause receiving `ERROR_MORE_DATA`

Comment: @Anton, yeah, you are right. That was it. Write it up as the answer so I can award points.

Comment: Also **don't use ASCII character encoding**. Never. Ever. ALWAYS use UNICODE when programming for windows, unless you are targeting Windows 98 or ME for some reason... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something weird in how you reuse one variable `size` for two consecutive calls as the in-out parameter. This may cause receiving `ERROR_MORE_DATA`.